# Gradle alias to property name

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-task

How can I create an "alias" for gradle property name?

For example, Android Instrumentation Runner provides an ability to execute only certain test class / method:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest \
   -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.TestSuiteName
```

How can I make this param name shorter?

I have tried creating custom task like this:

```
task executeTest {
    setProperty('android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class', 'com.example.TestSuiteName')
    dependsOn 'connectedAndroidTest'
}
```

But it blows up with `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`.

The same is with using `doLast {}` closure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `System.setProperty("key", "value")`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I believe your setting a property on the `Project` object, same as having `project.setProperty('key', 'val')`, but you want to add the property to the `System.properties`

Something like this should work to check if the task is to be executed first then set the system property.

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask("connectedAndroidTest") {
        System.setProperty('android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class', 'com.example.TestSuiteName')
    }
}
```